# How to read specific colum in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I have a Table called PRODUCT(item,qty,price for 1Kg,amount) after i added data into table i want to get total amount of amount column. So I know how to read all data from table. But i don't know how to read and add one field

here's my code:

```
    DBconnector db = new DBconnector();
    db.connect();          

    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) tblOrder.getModel();
    int numRow = dtm.getRowCount();//get rows
    int numCol = dtm.getColumnCount();//get colums

    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < numRow ; i++){
         for (int j = 0 ; j < numCol ; j++){
            list.add(tblOrder.getValueAt(i, j));  
        }
                   System.out.println(list);
        }
```

Anyone please can help me to do this?

Comment: do u want to read one column from jtable?? or from mysql table ? if from jtable,  remove the inner loop and use `list.add(tblOrder.getValueAt(i, column index));`

Comment: TableModel#getValueAt ?

Comment: question in this form isn't answerable here, for more info to read our FAQ, especiall part about MCVE could be interesting

Comment: thankx a lot every one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume your column 'amount' contains numbers, without a currency (so 5.12 instead of $5.12)

```
int numRow = dtm.getRowCount();
int columnAmount = 3; // TODO Set this to the correct column.
double totalAmount = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < numRow; i++) { // Loop over all rows
    // Add the value from column 'amount' to the total:
    totalAmount += Double.parseDouble(tblOrder.getValueAt(i, columnAmount).toString());
}

// TODO Do something with totalAmount
System.out.println(totalAmount);
```

Comment: this ll give a Error message : "incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to String". i think it may be because of this add().

Comment: Oh, that was a copy-paste error. The list isn't needed.

Comment: please whats - `Double.parseDouble(tblOrder.getValueAt(i, columnAmount).toString());`, because you can to store Double in database and in XxxTableModel too